# Difference between sip proxy and sip outbound proxy

Tags: sip, voip, sip-server, outbound

I'm little bit confused about sip proxy and sip outbound proxy? What is the basic difference between sip proxy and sip outbound proxy? Is it mandatory to use sip outbound proxy along with sip proxy? Can anyone point me out from the below image which one is the sip proxy and outbound proxy?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As your attached picture, it should be:

- User Agent: Client
- SIP outbound proxies: SIP Proxy port 5060 & SIP Proxy port 5070 when they're receiving incoming request from UA

A sip proxy can be understood as an "outbound proxy" or an "inbound proxy".
Details explanation can be describe as below:

> "Pretend you are a SIP User Agent, perhaps a very simple UA that
>   doesn't even do DNS lookups.
>
> A call coming to you is "inbound".
>
> It may hit your home proxy first, and receive treatment such as being
>   proxied to you based on your registered contact. This is an "inbound
>   service", and your home proxy is acting as an "inbound proxy".
>
> Now you want to make a call. Since you're making the call, it is going
>   "out", or can be called "outbound". You send this call to a proxy,
>   which looks up the request URI in DNS and sends the call on towards
>   its destination. This proxy is providing the "outbound service" of DNS
>   resolution, and is acting as an "outbound proxy" for this call.
>
> On any call there may be any number of inbound and outbound proxies
>   and services. Some proxies may even provide both sorts for a single
>   call.
>
> Assume the simple network UA1----P1----P2----UA2
>
> UA1 places a call to UA2."

//refer: https://www.ietf.org/mail-archive/web/sip/current/msg06276.html

Answer (score 2):

**SIP Proxy**

> A SIP proxy server receives a SIP request from a user agent or another
>   proxy and acts on behalf of the user agent in forwarding or responding
>   to the request.

**Sip Outbound Proxy**

> An outbound Proxy: A proxy that receives requests from a client, even
>   though it may not be the server resolved by the Request-URI.
>   Typically, a SIP user agent is manually configured with an outbound proxy, or
>   can learn about one through auto-configuration protocols.

Basically they are the same, the only difference, is that SIP Proxy treats requests both for `UAC` (client) and `UAS` (server), but SIP Outbound Proxy receives requests from `UAC`.
And, no, it's not mandatory to use SIP Outbound Proxy along with SIP Proxy.
What about scheme from your image, these are not proxy servers, but are registrar servers which are used to register requests of the users and keep the information from these requests.

Comment: So, for sip registration which  registrar server should I use?

Comment: do you own register server or have a sip account ?

Comment: I own a register server.